# Text transition/animation onclick in javascript function and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, animation, text, transition

I have a button triggering this function on click:

```
<button onclick="showAdvice()">Advice!</button>
<p id="text"></p>

<script>
    function showAdvice() {
        var advices = ["1","2","3"];
        var choose = Math.floor(Math.random() * advices.length);
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = advices[choose];
    }
</script>
```

The `onclick` action generates advices in "text" paragraph, they appear in random order. I want them to have a transition in between - opacity, fade out/fade in. How can I achieve this in CSS/JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  #pContainer {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
  }
  #pContainer > p {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  }
  #pContainer > p.show {
   opacity: 1;
  }
  #pContainer > p.hide {
   opacity: 0;
  }
 </style>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
 <button onclick="showAdvice()">Advice!</button>
 <div id="pContainer">
     <p id="text" class="show"></p>
     <p id="text02" class="hide"></p>
 </div>

    <script>
  function showAdvice() {
      var advices = ["1","2","3"];
         var choose = Math.floor(Math.random() * advices.length);

         $('#pContainer p.hide')
          .text(advices[choose])
          .removeClass('hide')
          .addClass('show')
          .siblings('p')
          .removeClass('show')
          .addClass('hide');
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to create animations.

```
function showAdvice() {
    $("#text").hide();
  var advices = ["1", "2", "3"];
  var choose = Math.floor(Math.random() * advices.length);
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = advices[choose];
  $("#text").fadeIn();
}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/90mxq8bf/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  #pContainer {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
  }
  #pContainer > p {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   /* transition: opacity 0.5s linear; */
  }
  #pContainer > p.show {
   /* opacity: 1; */
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-animation: showP 0.85s linear;
  }
  #pContainer > p.hide {
   /* opacity: 0; */
   opacity: 0;
   top: -50px;
   -webkit-animation: hideP 0.85s linear;
  }
   
   @-webkit-keyframes showP {
    0%{
     opacity: 0;
     top: -50px;
    }
    
    100%{
     opacity: 1;
     top: 0px
    }
   }

   @-webkit-keyframes hideP {
    0%{
     opacity: 1;
     top: 0px;
    }
    80%{
     opacity: 0;
    }
    90%{
     top: 105px; /* container height + 5*/
    }
    100%{
     opacity: 0;
     top: -50px;
    }
   }
 </style>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
 <button onclick="showAdvice()">Advice!</button>
 <div id="pContainer">
     <p id="text" class="show"></p>
     <p id="text02" class="hide"></p>
 </div>

    <script>
  function showAdvice() {
      var advices = ["1","2","3"];
         var choose = Math.floor(Math.random() * advices.length);

         $('#pContainer p.hide')
          .text(advices[choose])
          .removeClass('hide')
          .addClass('show')
          .siblings('p')
          .removeClass('show')
          .addClass('hide');
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```